# My build does not include my web site directive

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm not sure where I went off of the rails but I am trying to create a container for my web site. First I start off with a file called 'default':

```
server {
        root /var/www;
        index index.html;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
}
```

`var/www/` points to my web content with `index.html` being the default file for the content.

Then I create my very simple Dockerfile:

```
FROM httpd
MAINTAINER Jay Blanchard 

RUN httpd
ADD default /home/OARS/
```

In my Dockerfile I reference the default file from above, thinking this is what is needed to point to my web content. The default file happens to be in the same directory as the Docker file, but I give the path `/home/OARS/` as I have seen in some examples.

The build is successful:

```
foo@bar:/home/OARS$ sudo docker build -t oars-example .
Sending build context to Docker daemon 3.072 kB
Sending build context to Docker daemon
Step 0 : FROM httpd
 ---> cba1e4bb4caa
Step 1 : MAINTAINER Jay Blanchard
 ---> Using cache
 ---> e77807e98c6b
Step 2 : RUN httpd
 ---> Using cache
 ---> c0bff2fb1f9b
Step 3 : ADD default /home/OARS/
 ---> 3b4053fbc8d4
Removing intermediate container e02d27c4309d
Successfully built 3b4053fbc8d4
```

And the run appears to be successful:

```
foo@bar:/home/OARS$ sudo docker run -d -P oars-example
9598c176a706b19dd28dfab8de94e9c630e5781aca6930564d15182d21b0f6a5
```

> 9598c176a706        oars-example:latest                                                       "httpd-foreground"     6 seconds ago       Up 5 seconds                   0.0.0.0:32776->80/tcp   jovial_fermat

Yet when I go to the IP (with port 32776, there is something running on port 80 already) I do not get the index page I've specified in `/var/www`, but I do get the default index page from the Apache server.

Here is the log from the server:

```
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 000.000.000.000. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 000.000.000.000. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Tue May 19 16:59:17.457525 2015] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 1:tid 140053777708928] AH00489: Apache/2.4.12 (Unix) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue May 19 16:59:17.457649 2015] [core:notice] [pid 1:tid 140053777708928] AH00094: Command line: 'httpd -D FOREGROUND'
000.000.000.000 - - [19/May/2015:17:00:08 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 45
000.000.000.000 - - [19/May/2015:17:00:08 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 209
```

> I've changed the IP addresses in the logs just to keep things kosher.

Am I missing something obvious to make sure my web site files are being run in the container?

Comment: Try your run command as  `sudo docker run -d -p 8822:80 oars-example` and check on 8822 port if it displays `It works`

Comment: It always display 'It works', it just never displays what I am pointing to @Sabin

Comment: But, with just the commands above, you are not copying anything to `/var/www`. You are just adding that `default` file to `/home/OARS`. Is that supposed to be read automatically?

Comment: I was under the impression that it would be. Maybe that's where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Then what is the server directive about in the default file? the index.html in `var/www/` is not being read.

Comment: I used your command to create a container and there is no such folder as `var/www/`. Can you verify using `sudo docker exec -it <your-container-id> /bin/bash`?

Comment: @Sabin when I do that I am able to list the directory and look at the files. I see the index.html where "It works!" is (under htdocs). That means httpd is running fine.

Comment: So, isn't that what you're supposed to see? The thing that is in index.html?

Comment: I thought I was supposed to see the index.html from `/var/www/index.html` because of what is in the default file.

Comment: But if you go inside the container (doing `sudo docker exec -it ..`), do you see `/var/www/index.html` file? When I ran your commands, I cannot see that in my container.

Comment: I think I have it figured out. It isn't a straightforward as it seems to be. I'll likely write a tutorial once it is all done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you are trying to use a nginx config file within an Apache container.

Then, according to [the base container documentation](https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/httpd/), the correct way to specify a config file is:

```
# Dockerfile
FROM httpd
COPY ./my-httpd.conf /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
```

Comment: How is that an nginx config file?

Comment: Your "default" file has the syntax of an Nginx config file. Compare Nginx http://wiki.nginx.org/FullExample with Apache https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html